# Google Cloud Tasks availability in asia-southeast1

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask such question. Feel free to direct me to the right place.

According to https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#asia-pacific Cloud Tasks is available in the region `asia-southeast1` (but App Engine is not available in the region)

But from the Cloud Tasks [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview)

> To access the Cloud Tasks service using Cloud Tasks API , you must
> have a project that contains an App Engine app that hosts the Cloud
> Tasks queues that you create. This app is located in a specific region
> which serves as the LOCATION_ID parameter for your Cloud Tasks
> requests, so make a note of it. The app serves as the location for
> whatever queues the developer creates. The underlying Cloud Tasks
> service itself runs in that same location.

I assume that there should be App Engine configured for a particular region in order to use Cloud Tasks for that region. And since only 1 App Engine configuration can be made for each project, am I correct to assume that we can only create Cloud Tasks queue in only 1 region per project?

But `asia-southeast1` seems to have Cloud Tasks available, but not App Engine. Is the information on https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#asia-pacific incorrect or is there a way to create a Cloud Tasks queue in `asia-southeast1` ?

Comment: Good observation. Yes I think it's incorrect on the link. Or check if asia-southeast as app engine location and asia-southeast1 as cloud tasks location

Comment: In my opinion this is documentation error in this location page - i mean it should be marked as available for region where there is no App Engine. I strongly suggest to raise it at https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests